# how can I convert a nsnumber into a float

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to multiply the value of an nsnumber by a float but they are of course incompatible types. How can I cast the nsnumber to a float?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
float result = [myNSNumber floatValue] * myFloat;
```

Please check the "Accessing Numeric Values" section from [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber) class reference for converting to other types.

Comment: What if I put a double (like 1.0) into a NSNumber?

Answer (score 17):

Like so:

```
float value = [someNSNumber floatValue];
```